# D3 Vertical tree using NodeSize causing children nodes to have very high x value

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I am trying to use d3.js v7.8.5 to create a vertical tree. This is a component in a vue project.

This is my code:

```
<!-- VerticalTree.vue -->
<template>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export default {
  name: 'Chart',
  data() {
    return {
      margin: { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 },
      width: window.innerWidth - 40, // subtract margins
      height: window.innerHeight - 40, // subtract margins
      i: 0,
      duration: 750,
      rectW: 20,
      rectH: 16,
      horizontalSeparationBetweenNodes: 70,
      verticalSeparationBetweenNodes: 80,
      url: "<redacted>",
      app_count: true,
      app_data: null,
      root: null,
      svg: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {

      d3.json(this.url).then(data => {
        this.createChart(data);
      });

    },

    createChart(data) {

      const svg = d3
        .select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', this.width - this.margin.right - this.margin.left)
        .attr('height', this.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + 20 + ")");

      let treeLayout = d3.tree()
        .nodeSize([this.rectW + this.horizontalSeparationBetweenNodes, this.rectH + this.verticalSeparationBetweenNodes])
        .separation(function (a, b) {
          return a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1;
        });

      this.root = d3.hierarchy(data);

      treeLayout(this.root);

      if (this.root.children) {
        this.root.children.forEach(this.collapse);
      }

      // Draw links
      svg
        .selectAll('.link')
        .data(this.root.links())
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'link')
        .attr("id", "links")
        .attr('d', d3.linkVertical().x(d => d.x).y(d => d.y));

      // Draw nodes
      const nodes = svg
        .selectAll('.node')
        .data(this.root.descendants())
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr("id", "nodes")
        .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);

      nodes
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', 5)
        .style('fill', 'steelblue');

      nodes
        .append('text')
        .attr('dy', '0.31em')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', d => (d.children ? -8 : 20))
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text(d => d.data.name);

      console.log(this.root);
    },

    collapse(node) {
      if (node.children) {
        node._children = node.children;
        node._children.forEach(this.collapse);
        node.children = null;
      }
    },

  },
};
</script>
```

I need to use nodeSize as data is dynamically loaded and can vary. My root node is positioned correctly, but its children are not. When inspecting I found:

[html inspected in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtVlN.png)

I am not quite able to understand why the x coordinate would take such insane values. I previously used size and got it to work correctly, but my use case does not allow for it. If somebody could explain why this is happening then that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell without working code, but one bug that has happened to me before is adding values I expect to be numbers that turn out to be strings

i.e. "500"+"600" = will give you the string 500600
Whereas "500"-"600" will give you the number -100

Check you're not doing that in nodeSize